# Eliminar elementos repetidos de una coleccion de objetos

Tags: laravel-5, array

obtuve esta colección de ventas por productos:

```
$ventas = VentasProductos::withCount('producto')
                        ->orderBy('producto_count', 'desc')
                        ->take(5)
                        ->get();
```

pero en la vista me muestra los elementos repetidos, me cree esta linea de código pero no me elimina uno de los elementos repetidos:

```
if($ventas){
        foreach($ventas as $key=>$venta){
           if(array_key_exists($venta->id, $ventas)){
                unset($ventas[$key]);
          }
        }
    }
```

Pero al parecer estoy aplicando mal el `array_key_exists` y no se me elimina el elemento repetido.

```
#items: array:4 [▼
    0 => VentasProductos {#1791 ▼
      +table: "ventas_productos"
      +fillable: array:6 [▶]
      #casts: array:7 [▶]
      #connection: "mysql"
      #primaryKey: "id"
      #keyType: "int"
      +incrementing: true
      #with: []
      #withCount: []
      #perPage: 15
      +exists: true
      +wasRecentlyCreated: false
      #attributes: array:10 [▶]
      #original: array:10 [▼
        "id" => 8
        "cantidad" => 1
        "importe" => 6.0
        "importe_pagado" => 0.0
        "deuda" => 1
        "created_at" => null
        "updated_at" => null
        "producto_id" => 9
        "factura_id" => 11
        "producto_count" => 1
      ]
      #changes: []
      #dates: []
      #dateFormat: null
      #appends: []
      #dispatchesEvents: []
      #observables: []
      #relations: []
      #touches: []
      +timestamps: true
      #hidden: []
      #visible: []
      #guarded: array:1 [▶]
    }
    1 => VentasProductos {#1792 ▼
      +table: "ventas_productos"
      +fillable: array:6 [▶]
      #casts: array:7 [▶]
      #connection: "mysql"
      #primaryKey: "id"
      #keyType: "int"
      +incrementing: true
      #with: []
      #withCount: []
      #perPage: 15
      +exists: true
      +wasRecentlyCreated: false
      #attributes: array:10 [▼
        "id" => 10
        "cantidad" => 1
        "importe" => 6.0
        "importe_pagado" => 2.0
        "deuda" => 1
        "created_at" => "2018-03-26"
        "updated_at" => "2018-03-27"
        "producto_id" => 9
        "factura_id" => 17
        "producto_count" => 1
      ]
      #original: array:10 [▼
        "id" => 10
        "cantidad" => 1
        "importe" => 6.0
        "importe_pagado" => 2.0
        "deuda" => 1
        "created_at" => "2018-03-26"
        "updated_at" => "2018-03-27"
        "producto_id" => 9
        "factura_id" => 17
        "producto_count" => 1
      ]
      #changes: []
      #dates: []
      #dateFormat: null
      #appends: []
      #dispatchesEvents: []
      #observables: []
      #relations: []
      #touches: []
      +timestamps: true
      #hidden: []
      #visible: []
      #guarded: array:1 [▶]
    }
    2 => VentasProductos {#1793 ▶}
    3 => VentasProductos {#1794 ▶}
  ]
}
```

Y deberia salir solamente uno

Comment: ¿Puedes mostrar cómo te aparecen los elementos en la vista?

Comment: pregunto si lo que deseas es recibir valores no duplicados, no deberìas usar ->distinct() ? o al menos asi percibo tu pregunta igual no entendi

Comment: puedes hacer un filter con la collection que te devuelva.

Comment: si deseo recibir id de productos no duplicados

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Con la función **withCount** obtienes la cantidad de elementos resultado de la relación con otra tabla, sin tener que cargarlos. El problema es que cuando lo llamas desde la entidad que tiene la relación de muchos a uno, se pueden repetir elementos y principalmente la nueva propiedad *_count que te agregará a los resultados siempre será 1. por consiguiente te recomiendo que llames **withCount** desde la entidad que tiene la relación de 1 a muchos, logrando obtener elementos no repetidos y la cantidad real de las relaciones con la otra entidad.

```
$prod = Productos::withCount('ventas_productos')
                  ->orderBy('ventas_productos_count', 'desc')
                  ->take(5)
                  ->get();
```